# self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer showing null in iOS SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I wan't to use **SWRevealViewController** in my application for that i follow steps as per given link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SUV1YY2yxQ".

But my application get crashed at this line

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Complier showing following error

> terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'.

Please check my story board design

[image: attached is my story board design--- here Reveal View Controller is my initial view from this view connection segue 1 for left menu list (Simple view controller table view added programmatically) 2 for subclass of navigation controller and view controller is my root view controller..after submitting right credential application push next view i.e. Dashboard six option view controller (which has blue background)]

[image: DashBoardSixOptionViewController]

Bellow are my Code for blue background view where i want to open reveal view controller  .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface DashboardSixOptionViewController : UIViewController 
{

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) SWRevealViewController *revealViewController;
@end
```

.m file

```
@interface DashboardSixOptionViewController ()

@end

@implementation DashboardSixOptionViewController
@synthesize revealViewController = _revealViewController;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"gesture desc::%@",self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer);


    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
-(void)configureView
{
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    CGRect dashboardNavFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
//    dashboardNavFrame.size.height += 5;

    self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:dashboardNavFrame];

    [self.toolBar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [self.toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    //disable any back btn
    self.toolBar.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
    self.toolBar.clipsToBounds = NO;
    [self.toolBar setTag:700];

    NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    UIImage *imgOption;

    imgOption = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgOptionsIOS7.png"];

    UIButton *aOptionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    [aOptionButton setEnabled:NO];
    aOptionButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgOption.size.width, imgOption.size.height);
    [aOptionButton setImage:imgOption forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [aOptionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLeftMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aOptionButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aOptionButton];
    [btn setTarget:self.revealViewController];
    [btn setAction:@selector(revealToggle:)];
    [buttons addObject:btn];
  [self.toolBar setItems:buttons animated:YES];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.toolBar];

}
```

from view controller DashboardSixOptionView view push programatically below is my code

```
DashboardSixOptionView  = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashboardStoryBoardWithSixOption"];
    DashboardSixOptionView.arrTableViewHreaders = self.arrForMenuOption;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DashboardSixOptionView animated:YES];
```

Please help me out why i getting crash.

Thanks in advanced
Priyanka

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer` is `nil`, because you created a property for the SWRevealViewController but didn't assign any value in `viewDidLoad`.

Have you set all the classes properly in your Storyboard?

Plus, why do you use `@synthesize` and a class variable for your SWRevealViewController? There is no need anymore to do that.

I recommend you to take a look to [this great tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) for SWRevealViewController.

Comment: Hi,thanks for replay.i just tried with creating property and @synthesize.. Followed this link  "http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/" but still getting same error.

Comment: No, what I mean is that you don't need to use synthesize anymore. Just use the property. Just delete these lines:

'@synthesize revealViewController = _revealViewController;` (in the .m file)

`{

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController;

}` (in the .h file)

Check again the tutorial and check what classes did you set in your storyboard. Look for it in the Identity Inspector (right panel, third icon starting from the left).

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the new object for `SWRevealViewController` in `DashboardSixOptionViewController.h` or `DashboardSixOptionViewController.m` file.  Instead of it, use the same object which is created in `SWRevealViewController` class.

*DashboardSixOptionViewController.m Class*

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
-(void)viewDidLoad{
_barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: created toolbar with bar button and place that toll bar on navigation bar UIButton *aOptionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aOptionButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgOption.size.width, imgOption.size.height);
    [aOptionButton setImage:imgOption forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aOptionButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aOptionButton];
    [btn setTarget:self.revealViewController];
    [btn setAction:@selector(revealToggle:)];
    [buttons addObject:btn];
[self.toolBar setItems:buttons animated:YES];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.toolBar];

Comment: From your storyBoard, It's noticed that LeftMenuList is a subclass of UIViewController.. This should be subclass of UITableViewController.. Try this

Comment: Hi Daya Kevin,i have tried with sub class of table view but still i m getting self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognize = nil from below line [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem !!
If you want to connect to menu view controller you have to connect it through `swrevealviewcontrtoller` so check your segues once again and this solved my issue and I used.

```
[self.revealviewcontroller pangesturerecogonizer];
```

Instead of

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```